# How was apache2 able to use 8+GB ram "in idle"? (oom-killer)

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, ubuntu-22.04

I bought a vps in Contabo, using ubuntu22, installed apache2, php, mariadb.Sometimes the apache2 uses all of my memory. Literally all. At idle, not really anything was running.

*A php process was running in the picture but right after this happened I stopped it and restarted apache2 and the memory again got to 8gb in just like 10sec. So I think it is not related to the problem, I used this php script on my old vps in the past year.'*

I kept starting apache2 but it was eating 8gb ram and killed. I left it and started it again after like 30min and everything was working fine. Was it some kind of attack? It's a new vps, I don't think I was the target, maybe the IP address's previous owner.

[htop image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMAXI.png)

syslog:

```
May 12 18:34:57 vps postfix/smtpd[2489]: connect from unknown[80.91.95.233]
May 12 18:34:59 vps postfix/smtpd[2489]: disconnect from unknown[80.12.95.103] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953580] systemd-resolve invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953622] CPU: 0 PID: 426 Comm: systemd-resolve Not tainted 5.15.0-71-generic #78-Ubuntu
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953630] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.13.0-48-gd9c812dda519-prebuilt.qemu.org 04/01/2014
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953636] Call Trace:
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953642]  <TASK>
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953689]  show_stack+0x52/0x5c
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953746]  dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x63
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953766]  dump_stack+0x10/0x16
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953768]  dump_header+0x53/0x228
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953785]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953788]  out_of_memory+0x106/0x2e0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953814]  __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0x9b7/0xa80
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953827]  __alloc_pages+0x311/0x330
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953830]  alloc_pages+0x9e/0x1e0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953836]  __page_cache_alloc+0x7e/0x90
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953838]  pagecache_get_page+0x152/0x590
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953841]  ? page_cache_ra_unbounded+0x166/0x210
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953847]  filemap_fault+0x488/0xab0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953849]  ? filemap_map_pages+0x309/0x400
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953852]  __do_fault+0x3c/0x120
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953859]  do_read_fault+0xeb/0x160
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953862]  do_fault+0xa0/0x2e0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953864]  handle_pte_fault+0x1cd/0x240
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953867]  __handle_mm_fault+0x405/0x6f0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953871]  handle_mm_fault+0xd8/0x2c0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953874]  do_user_addr_fault+0x1c9/0x670
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953889]  exc_page_fault+0x77/0x170
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953902]  asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953909] RIP: 0033:0x7f26b057d170
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953944] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f26b057d146.
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953945] RSP: 002b:00007ffcc57c3dc8 EFLAGS: 00010202
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953951] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00000000000001fa RCX: 0000000000000038
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953956] RDX: 0000000000000040 RSI: 00000000000001fa RDI: 0000000000000000
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953957] RBP: 00007ffcc57c3e30 R08: 0000000000000038 R09: 0000000000000003
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953958] R10: 000056550016f418 R11: 0000000000000029 R12: 00000000000001fa
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953960] R13: 00007ffcc57c3e2e R14: 000056550016f330 R15: 00007ffcc57c3e2f
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953968]  </TASK>
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953972] Mem-Info:
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953979] active_anon:222500 inactive_anon:1752915 isolated_anon:0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953979]  active_file:82 inactive_file:20 isolated_file:0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953979]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953979]  slab_reclaimable:9682 slab_unreclaimable:7289
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953979]  mapped:1332 shmem:1388 pagetables:9526 bounce:0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953979]  kernel_misc_reclaimable:0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953979]  free:25343 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953987] Node 0 active_anon:890000kB inactive_anon:7011660kB active_file:328kB inactive_file:80kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:5328kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:5552kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB kernel_stack:2928kB pagetables:38104kB all_unreclaimable? yes
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.953992] Node 0 DMA free:14336kB min:128kB low:160kB high:192kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15360kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954001] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2884 7862 7862 7862
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954005] Node 0 DMA32 free:44528kB min:24744kB low:30928kB high:37112kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:20900kB inactive_anon:2940008kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:28kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:3129192kB managed:3027340kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954010] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 4978 4978 4978
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954014] Node 0 Normal free:42508kB min:42708kB low:53384kB high:64060kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:868928kB inactive_anon:4071876kB active_file:616kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:5242880kB managed:5097560kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954018] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954052] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 14336kB
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954063] Node 0 DMA32: 116*4kB (UM) 116*8kB (UM) 53*16kB (UME) 40*32kB (UM) 18*64kB (UME) 9*128kB (UME) 3*256kB (UE) 7*512kB (UE) 14*1024kB (UME) 2*2048kB (ME) 4*4096kB (M) = 44992kB
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954091] Node 0 Normal: 248*4kB (UME) 166*8kB (UME) 43*16kB (UME) 54*32kB (ME) 17*64kB (UME) 4*128kB (UME) 2*256kB (UE) 4*512kB (UME) 24*1024kB (UM) 5*2048kB (M) 0*4096kB = 43712kB
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954116] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954126] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954128] 9887 total pagecache pages
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954131] 8351 pages in swap cache
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954132] Swap cache stats: add 4102800, delete 4094427, find 139028/194627
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954134] Free swap  = 0kB
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954135] Total swap = 8388604kB
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954136] 2097016 pages RAM
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954137] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954137] 61951 pages reserved
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954138] 0 pages hwpoisoned
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954139] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954139] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954144] [    255]     0   255     5855      661    77824      184          -250 systemd-journal
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954152] [    294]     0   294     6334       14    73728      390         -1000 systemd-udevd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954156] [    415]   100   415     4030       40    69632      209             0 systemd-network
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954159] [    420]   102   420    22339       41    69632      173             0 systemd-timesyn
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954161] [    426]   101   426     6350      114    94208      917             0 systemd-resolve
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954164] [    428]     0   428    59972       55    90112      162             0 accounts-daemon
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954166] [    429]     0   429     2373       26    53248       38             0 cron
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954168] [    430]   103   430     2148       80    57344       92          -900 dbus-daemon
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954171] [    436]     0   436    20691       50    57344       40             0 irqbalance
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954174] [    437]     0   437     8845       54   102400     2103             0 networkd-dispat
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954176] [    438]   104   438    55601       89    81920      288             0 rsyslogd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954179] [    439]     0   439     3836      100    69632      151             0 systemd-logind
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954181] [    460]     0   460    58622       82    94208      127             0 polkitd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954183] [    469]     0   469    28087      128   114688     1904             0 unattended-upgr
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954185] [    479]     0   479     2193       12    53248        9             0 agetty
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954188] [    495]     0   495     3856       42    69632      367         -1000 sshd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954190] [    522]   110   522   709199   147108  2666496   149316             0 mariadbd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954194] [    604]     0   604     4307      100    77824      524             0 sshd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954196] [    607]     0   607     4232       20    69632      348             0 systemd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954198] [    608]     0   608    25829      189    90112      641             0 (sd-pam)
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954200] [    631]     0   631     1972       43    57344      253             0 sftp-server
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954203] [    661]     0   661     4301        1    77824      608             0 sshd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954205] [    681]     0   681     2813        2    65536      402             0 bash
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954207] [    703]     0   703   579185   107661  4460544   421389             0 php
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954210] [    709]     0   709     4302       60    73728      551             0 sshd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954212] [    729]     0   729     2813       57    61440      349             0 bash
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954215] [   1270]     0  1270    10305       15    73728      144             0 master
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954217] [   1271]   109  1271    10388        5    73728      160             0 pickup
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954220] [   1272]   109  1272    10435        0    73728      176             0 qmgr
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954223] [   1292]   109  1292    11830       15    86016      416             0 tlsmgr
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954237] [   1293]   109  1293    10387       30    69632      136             0 anvil
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954240] [   1517]     0  1517     4305       11    77824      599             0 sshd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954242] [   1539]     0  1539     2492       42    57344       31             0 bash
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954262] [   1559]     0  1559     4306       95    69632      525             0 sshd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954264] [   1580]     0  1580     1968       53    53248      248             0 sftp-server
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954277] [   1977]   109  1977    11983       68    81920      449             0 smtpd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954279] [   2094]     0  2094    65540      897   221184     2044             0 apache2
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954281] [   2095]    33  2095    65704      379   225280     2145             0 apache2
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954284] [   2096]    33  2096  3367635  1704713 26697728  1506468             0 apache2
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954287] [   2097]    33  2097    65705      240   225280     2131             0 apache2
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954289] [   2098]    33  2098    65698      226   196608     2098             0 apache2
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954291] [   2099]    33  2099    65706      291   225280     2135             0 apache2
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954293] [   2108]    33  2108    65704      292   225280     2132             0 apache2
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954295] [   2133]    33  2133    65705      279   225280     2132             0 apache2
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954297] [   2134]    33  2134    65706      833   225280     2205             0 apache2
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954299] [   2135]    33  2135    65704      278   225280     2133             0 apache2
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954302] [   2360]     0  2360     2972      406    61440      106             0 htop
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954305] [   2489]   109  2489    11983       64    86016      446             0 smtpd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954307] [   2495]   109  2495    11983      447    90112       69             0 smtpd
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954310] [   2516]     0  2516     3231       13    57344      191             0 cron
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954312] [   2522]     0  2522      722        0    45056       25             0 sh
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954314] [   2524]     0  2524     3522        0    73728      215             0 sudo
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954316] [   2538]     0  2538    25069       16    98304      722             0 curl
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954318] [   2635]     0  2635     3231      196    57344        8             0 cron
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954321] [   2636]     0  2636     3231      196    57344        8             0 cron
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954323] [   2637]     0  2637     3231      196    57344        8             0 cron
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954326] [   2638]     0  2638      722       22    45056        0             0 sh
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954328] [   2639]     0  2639     3523      213    69632        0             0 sudo
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954330] [   2640]     0  2640      722       24    45056        0             0 sh
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954332] [   2641]     0  2641     3522      212    65536        0             0 sudo
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954334] [   2642]     0  2642      722       24    45056        0             0 sh
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954336] [   2643]     0  2643     3522      214    65536        0             0 sudo
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954339] [   2644]     0  2644    25069      738    94208        0             0 curl
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954341] [   2645]     0  2645    25069      739    98304        0             0 curl
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954343] [   2646]     0  2646    25069      738    90112        0             0 curl
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954348] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/apache2.service,task=apache2,pid=2096,uid=33
May 12 18:35:16 vps kernel: [ 3627.954398] Out of memory: Killed process 2096 (apache2) total-vm:13470540kB, anon-rss:6815944kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:2908kB, UID:33 pgtables:26072kB oom_score_adj:0
May 12 18:35:16 vps postfix/smtpd[2495]: connect from unknown[80.94.95.203]
May 12 18:35:16 vps systemd[1]: apache2.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
May 12 18:35:18 vps systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
May 12 18:35:18 vps systemd[1]: apache2.service: Consumed 36.476s CPU time.
May 12 18:35:18 vps systemd[1]: system.slice: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
May 12 18:35:18 vps postfix/smtpd[1977]: connect from unknown[141.98.10.121]
May 12 18:35:18 vps postfix/smtpd[1977]: disconnect from unknown[141.91.10.151] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
May 12 18:35:19 vps postfix/smtpd[2495]: disconnect from unknown[80.93.95.203] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
May 12 18:35:34 vps postfix/smtpd[2489]: connect from unknown[80.94.91.2
```

Access log was literally empty at that time.
So I'm not sure what it was, was it some attack or not.

Please tell me if I should attach more log or info.

Edit: in php.ini I changed these:

```
memory_limit = 1024M,
max_execution_time = -1
```

In mariadb config I changed these:

```
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
innodb_log_file_size = 1024M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
```

(at apache settings, I didn't change anything)

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: @TomTom I would like to know why this oom-kill have happened. Unfortunately, this happens about once a day. What other information do you think I should add to the question?

Comment: It happens because the process used more memory than allowed. Siple. WHY is a question for competent people to debug - our crystal ball is bugged.

Comment: Please edit your question to add your httpd and php configuration, especially MPM and how you mange php processes. Also share your mariadb configuration, especially the config directives cited by the memory allocation KB articles.

Comment: @JohnMahowald at php.ini I only edited these: memory_limit = 1024M, max_execution_time = -1. If you mean httpd for apache, I edited nothing, it was just a simple sudo apt install apache2. At mariadb I edited only these in the config: key_buffer_size         = 256M, max_allowed_packet      = 1024M, innodb_log_file_size    = 1024M, innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M. So I can say the setup is pretty basic.

Comment: szlev add these information to the question not as comment and these are not the default settings sofar why did you change it?

Comment: @djdomi Okey added these to the questions. Why I changed these? Because I needed more memory limit and more execution time in php then the default 128M and 300sec. At MariaDB config I'm saving big datas to sql sometimes.

Comment: @JaromandaX the first entry (higlighted with light blue), the /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start doesn't the apache itself?

Comment: Oh my ... I completely missed that :p